# node.js hapi.js socket memory leak on server AWS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, memory-leaks, hapi.js

I have a stack of servers on AWS, and it seems to be leaking memory.  A heapdump is showing that I have ever increasing Sockets in an Array, with the peer of those Sockets to be the ELBs that sit in front of the server instances.

The ELBs ping with a health check every 6 seconds.

[image: heapdump]

How do I close these sockets if I am using hapi.js?  How do I fix this memory leak?

```
const config = require('./config');
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Path = require('path');
const Fs = require('fs');

server = new Hapi.Server({
  debug: { request: ['error'] },
  connections: {
    routes: {
      files: {
        relativeTo: Path.join(__dirname, 'public')
      }
    }
  }
})

var connectionDict = {
  port: config.port,
  host: config.host}

server.connection(connectionDict);
module.exports = server;

server.start(function () {
      setImmediate(function(){
        server.log([CONTROLLER_NAME, "server-start"], 'Server started at: ' + server.info.uri);
      });
    });

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/',
  handler: function (request, reply) {
    return reply('Welcome to your API!\n').header("Connection","Close");
  }
});

setInterval(function (){
 global.gc();
}, 60000);
```

One interesting tidbit is that this server has virtually no load - the only thing hitting the servers are the ELBs.

The sockets seen above are essentially repeats of the same peer connection.  I'm not sure why the server is not reusing the existing socket and creating new ones.

The .header on the reply also seems to be doing nothing.  Sockets will leak whether or not "Connection:close" is on the return header.

Unfortunately, the global.gc() also doesn't clean up the sockets.

**EDIT**
Not that it matters, but I am using a t2.micro instance.

Simpler code, still leaking:

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Fs = require('fs');

server = new Hapi.Server();
var connectionDict = {
  port: 8443,
  host: '0.0.0.0',
  tls: {
    key: Fs.readFileSync('./cert/https/projectchange.pem'),
    cert: Fs.readFileSync('./cert/https/projectchange.cert'),
    passphrase: 'somepassword'
    }
  }
server.connection(connectionDict);

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/',
  handler: function (request, reply) {
    return reply('Welcome to Change API!\n').header("Connection","Close");
  }
});

server.start(function (err) {
  console.log('Server started');
});

require('heapdump');
Fs.readdirSync('.').map(function (filename) {
  if (filename.match(/^heapdump-/)) {
    console.log(filename);
    Fs.unlinkSync(filename);
  }
});
setInterval(function heapDumper() {
  process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGUSR2');
}, 60000);
```

Comment: I would call server.route method before server.start.  Also why do you call setImmediate after server.start and then not listen to error returned from server.start method.

Comment: I saw your issue on github, I think your  problem is how your are calling methods

Comment: I made your changes.  No difference.

Comment: Post your code on github issue to see if the can help you trace your leak.

Comment: I've been seeing this issue with hapi v16 & node v9.2
Heapdump shows sockets array is continuously increasing. Sockets are not getting released